# fiz um quadrado que se move para todos os lados e gostava de definir uns limites ate onde pode andar

Tags: javascript, html

Resumidamente gostava de definir limites onde o quadrado possa andar, envio de seguida o meu codigo e agradeço qualquer ajuda.

```js
var topo=50;
var esq = 200;
 
function cima(){
   topo -= 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.top = topo + "px";
}                       
function baixo(){
   topo += 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.top = topo + "px";
}           

function esquerda(){
   esq -= 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.left = esq + "px";
}

function direita(){
   esq += 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.left = esq + "px";
}


function rosa(){

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
}

function amarelo(){

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function azul(){

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
#quadrado{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 200px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: red;
 }
 table{
        width: 200px;
        border: none;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Quadrado móvel</h1>
<div id="quadrado"></div>



<table>

     <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button onclick="cima();">Cima</button></td>
            <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><button onclick="esquerda();">Esquerda</button></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><button onclick="direita();">Direita</button></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button onclick="baixo();">Baixo</button></td>
            <td></td>
     </tr>
     
     
     
</table>

<h1>cores de fundo</h1>
<table>
<tr>
            <td><button onclick="rosa();">pink</button></td>
            
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><button onclick="amarelo();">yelow</button></td>
            
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><button onclick="azul();">blue</button></td>
            
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: você pode validar o valor e caso esteja "fora" dos limites retornar sem alterar, por exemplo: `function cima(){  if (top < 0) return;
   topo -= 5;`, e pode fazer isso com todas as posições, basta colocar os limites. Editei sua pergunta pra ficar mais fácil de entender o funcionamento

Answer (score 2):

Como comentei, em cada função antes de mudar o valor da posição basta validar com os valores limites:

```js
var topo=50;
var esq = 200;

function cima(){
   if (topo < 0) return;
   topo -= 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.top = topo + "px";
}                       
function baixo(){
   if (topo > 100) return;
   topo += 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.top = topo + "px";
}           

function esquerda(){
   if (esq < 150) return;
   esq -= 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.left = esq + "px";
}

function direita(){
   if (esq > 250) return;
   esq += 5;
   document.getElementById("quadrado").style.left = esq + "px";
}


function rosa(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
}

function amarelo(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function azul(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
#quadrado{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 200px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: red;
 }
 table{
        width: 200px;
        border: none;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Quadrado móvel</h1>
<div id="quadrado"></div>



<table>

     <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button onclick="cima();">Cima</button></td>
            <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><button onclick="esquerda();">Esquerda</button></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><button onclick="direita();">Direita</button></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button onclick="baixo();">Baixo</button></td>
            <td></td>
     </tr>
     
     
     
</table>

<h1>cores de fundo</h1>
<table>
<tr>
            <td><button onclick="rosa();">pink</button></td>
            
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><button onclick="amarelo();">yelow</button></td>
            
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><button onclick="azul();">blue</button></td>
            
     </tr>
</table>
```